# The code was working fine few days ago(solidity)

Tags: solidity, truffle-migration

Error parsing C:\Users\"directory"\example.sol: ParsedContract.sol:45:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
}
^
Compilation failed. See above.

And yes, pragma solidity includes a ';'

Comment: Please provide more details or even your code for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without showing us your full smart contract it's pretty difficult to find the root cause of the error.

However, I was able to reproduce a similar error by adding an extra `}` to the end of the smart contract.

**Check for any extra `}` in your code and delete them**.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I've been making lot of these silly mistakes lately. Constantly working on it.